# how to trace from target to source data in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.7, traversal

I want to traverse each data in the list/dictionary- here in the below input

`{mapping1: [(b,c),(a,b),(c,d)],mapping2: [(a,b),(b,c),(e,f),(d,e),(c,f)]}`

for mapping 1 d is the destination and a being source

for mapping 2: f is the destination, a and d being source.

So this links or traces can vary.

Below is my input

`{mapping1: [(b,c),(a,b),(c,d)],mapping2: [(a,b),(b,c),(e,f),(d,e),(c,f)]}`

Output is:

[image]

Comment: can there be multiple sources?

Comment: Yes, There Can be multiple sources. @TharunK

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the DAG concept, and find the nodes with no outdegrees i.e destination, and nodes with no in-degrees i.e source

For python, I am making use of networkx to build the DAG and matplotlib to plot and save the mapping.

```
pip install networkx matplotlib
```

You can add your mapping to the inputList variable. Just make sure to give it as a list of character tuples. The output will be a `g2.png` file present in the same directory as the script

```
import networkx as nx
from numpy import add

inputList = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('e', 'f'), ('d', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]
invertPairs =[]
for x,y in inputList:
    invertPairs.append((y,x))

g2 = nx.DiGraph()
g2.add_edges_from(invertPairs)
plt.tight_layout()
nx.draw_networkx(g2, arrows=True)
plt.savefig("g2.png", format="PNG")
plt.clf()
```

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Hey @TharunK  Thanks for the suggestion. But here I cant see that I am printing path

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre, I have added mapping plot now, please check